# Linux: How to use onboard graphics card for graphics and not the dedicated GPGPU?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, xorg, gpgpu

I recently bought a GPGPU (a Nvidia GEFORCE GTX 950 card) so I could use CUDA wrappers in my C code.  After installing CUDA 8.0 and plugging in my monitors into my onboard graphics card (not the GPGPU), I run "nvidia-smi" and I see the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1054    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             305MiB |
|    0      1805    G   compiz                                          84MiB |
|    0      4179    G   ...MainFrame --force-fieldtrials=*AppBannerT    80MiB |
|    0      5224    G   unity-control-center                             1MiB |
|    0      6925    C   python3                                         52MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Python3 is the only thing I actually want using this device.  How can I ensure that my GPGPU is not being used by Xorg or any process that is for graphics?  I know my onboard graphics card can use two monitors no problem, so I would really like it if these processes were instead ran on that.

In case it matters, I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on an ASUS machine.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have fixed this on my machine.  Unfortunately I have no idea why what I did fixed anything..  Remember, if you you have your monitors plugged into the Nvidia GPU it will use them so make sure they're plugged into the on board graphics.  If all your monitors are plugged into your on board graphics and you run nvidia-smi and still see processes like xorg, unity-control-center, then try this.  Search for additional drivers and click on the application.  You should see a menu for your nvidia graphics card that has a bunch of drivers available on it, click use the xOrg server and then click apply the changes.  Restart the computer. Upon reboot go back to additional drivers and switch back to the Nvidia driver you were using before you switch to xorg.  Log out and then back in again.  To check that it worked, type "nvidia-smi" into the terminal and you should see that no processes are running on your GPGPU.

I have no idea why this works, if anyone would like to offer an explanation that would be awesome. If not, I hope this works for others with this problem.  If it doesn't I'm sorry to say I won't be of much help.